# Why a recipient does not receive an email in HTML format (only text) that I send using PHP?

Tags: php, html, email

Whatever I do, whatever headers I elaborate, it does not work.
Even I have inserted content type in the header (within the message itself). I'll go crazy ...

Php version: 5.2.17

Machine: Linux

Kernel version: 2.6.32-46.1.BHsmp (if this matters)

```
<?php
$headers = "From: <sender@mydomain.com>" . "\n";
$headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\n";
$headers .= "http-equiv='Content-Type' content='text/html; charset=iso-8859-1'\r\n";
$emailBody="<html>";
$emailBody .= "<head>";
$emailBody .= "<meta http-equiv='Content-Type' content='text/html; charset=iso-8859-1'>";
$emailBody .= "</head>";
$emailBody .= "<body>";
$emailBody .= "Hello Dear, <br><b>Bla Bla</b><br> See you later. <br>Bye.";
$emailBody .= "</body>";
$emailBody .= "</head>";
$emailBody .= "</html>";
mail("<recipient@gmail.com>", "Testing some HTML mail", $emailBody, $headers);
?>
```

Waiting for an expert in PHP/HTML to review the code above.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: maybe he doesnt want your HTML mail and deactivated display of it.

Comment: no, the recipient did not modified anything in gmail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**This Will work Simply ..**

```
$to  = 'aidan@example.com' . ', '; // note the comma
$to .= 'wez@example.com';

// subject
$subject = 'Birthday Reminders for August';



$message = '
<html>
<head>
  <title>Birthday Reminders ...';



$headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";

// Additional headers
$headers .= 'To: Mary <mary@example.com>, Kelly <kelly@example.com>' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'From: Birthday Reminder <birthday@example.com>' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Cc: birthdayarchive@example.com' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Bcc: birthdaycheck@example.com' . "\r\n";

// Mail it
mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try setting the headers in this format instead:

```
$headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";
```

Comment: When sending html formatted mails to gmail accounts you might notice that the html is shown in plain text. This happens when you send from an unix system and gmail treats the "\r\n" line ends in a wrong way. Use "\n" instead at it will be fine. 

Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1\n
instead of
Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1\r\n(an excerpt out of http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php)

Answer (score 0):

If you are willing to use a library like PHPMailer it makes sending HTML messages SO much easier. You don't have to worry about boundary strings, headers, etc.

Here is some sample code:

```
$mailer = new PHPMailer();
$mailer->IsHTML(true);
$mailer->ContentType = 'text/html';
$mailer->FromName = $from;
$mailer->Subject = $subject;
$mailer->Body = $yourHtmlContent;
$mailer->AddAddress($someRecipientAddress);
$mailer->Send();
```

Comment: Where I can find this PHPMailer library? Is it installed by default in PHP? I guess not, but still asking ...